# Can't return multiple object on asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

I can't return an integer and an `IEnumerable` from my Web API. `IEnumerable` has vm classes.

This is `Response.cs`:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TheMPDB_API.DataClasses;

namespace TheMPDB_API.Responses
{
    public class Response
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Data> ResponseData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is `ModpacksResponse.cs`:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TheMPDB_API.DataClasses;

namespace TheMPDB_API.Responses
{
    public class ModpacksResponse : Response
    {
        public ModpacksResponse(IEnumerable<ModpackData> data)
        {
            StatusCode = 200;
            ResponseData = data;
        }
    }
}
```

This is `ModpackData.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TheMPDB_API.DataClasses
{
    public class ModpackData : Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MainImage { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string WikiPage { get; set; }
        public string IssuesPage { get; set; }
        public string LicenseName { get; set; }
        public string LicenseDescription { get; set; }
        public string DonateLink { get; set; }
        public string SourceUrl { get; set; }
        public List<int> AuthorIds { get; set; }
        public List<int> FileIds { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is `Data.cs`:

```cs
namespace TheMPDB_API.DataClasses
{
    public class Data
    {
    }
}
```

This code returns a `ModpacksResponse` in controller:

```cs
return new ModpacksResponse(allModpacks.ToList());
```

This is the return of request.

```
{"statusCode":200,"responseData":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}
```

This is the allModpacks definition

```cs
IQueryable<ModpackData> allModpacks;
allModpacks = (from x in Db.Modpacks
               select new ModpackData()
                          {
                              Id = x.Id,
                              Description = x.Description,
                              Name = x.Name,
                              CreateDate = x.CreateDate,
                              DonateLink = x.DonateLink,
                              IssuesPage = x.IssuesPage,
                              LicenseDescription = x.LicenseDescription,
                              LicenseName = x.LicenseName,
                              MainImage = x.MainImage,
                              SourceUrl = x.SourceUrl,
                              WikiPage = x.WikiPage,
                              AuthorIds = (from utm in Db.UsersToModpacks
                                           where utm.ModpackId == x.Id
                                           select utm.UserId).ToList(),
                              FileIds = (from f in Db.ModpackFiles
                                         where f.ModpackId == x.Id
                                         select f.Id).ToList()
                          });
```

I am using .NET 5.0.

Comment: You didn't describe the problem. Do you get an error? Is the result array empty? Is there any data to return in the first place or is `allModpacks` empty? What is it anyway? Returning multiple properties works. Returning multiple items workds.

Comment: BTW .NET 5.0 went out of support last month. It was only an interim, single-year version. The long-term-support version is .NET 6. The .NET Core lifecycle was announces several years ago when .NET Core 3.1 was released

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sorry, i added image now.

Comment: Post results and errors as text, not images. Images can't be copied, googled or compiled

Comment: {"statusCode":200,"responseData":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}

Comment: it doesnt gives any error

Comment: Post that in the question itself. It looks like the wrong type was used though. Again, what is `allModpacks` and where does it get its values from? If it contains only `Data` instances, the result is expected. `Data` has no properties

Comment: Break `return new ModpacksResponse(allModpacks.ToList())` into two separate lines and inspect what `allModpacks.ToList()` returns.

Comment: allModpacks getting from Database with linq. and its type is IQueryable<ModpackData> and Get method returns ModpacksResponse as Response. and Response getting ModpackData as Data.

Comment: Post the DbContext and entities code. If you use `DbSet<Data>` you'll get nothing because `Data` has no properties. Your entity should be `DbSet<ModpackData>`.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization with System.Text.Json doesn't work on the derived class or polymorphic types, but it works purely based on the datatype that you specified in the response model. In your case, you use the `ResponseData` type as `IEnumerable<Data>`, so during serialization, it serializes your objects based on the `Data` class type, instead of the `ModpackData`, and that's why you received the empty objects in the API response.

You can solve this problem in different ways, but below I've specified the code snippet which uses the generics to solve your problem.

```
public class Response<T>
{
  public int StatusCode { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<T> ResponseData { get; set; }
}

public class ModpacksResponse : Response<ModpackData>
{
   public ModpacksResponse(IEnumerable<ModpackData> data)
   {
       StatusCode = 200;
       ResponseData = data;
   }
}
```